# Dúvidas sobre a medalha "Tenaz"

Tags: suporte, medalhas

> Respostas aceitas com pontuação igual a zero: mais de 5 e 20% do total

- Esse mais de 5 : contam minhas auto pergunta e resposta?
- 20% do total : de todas das respostas que eu já dei?

Se for 20% de todas respostas que já dei, não seria meio "um caso especial"?, pois a medida que eu der respostas mais impossível de torna consegui-la.

Eu que tenho 130 respostas atualmente, destas eu teria de ter aceito em 26 todas com um total de 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esse mais de 5 : contam minhas auto pergunta e resposta?

Não, não contam.

> 20% do total : de todas das respostas que eu já dei?

Do total de respostas aceitas de sua autoria. Não considerando as auto-respostas.

> Eu que tenho 130 respostas atualmente, destas eu teria de ter aceito em 26 todas com um total de 0?

Não importa a quantidade de respostas, importa a quantidade de respostas aceitas. Dessa 130 respostas, se você tiver 20 respostas aceitas, que não sejam auto-respostas, e dessas 20, 6 estiverem com zero pontos, você está apto a receber a medalha.

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi como que ganha ela. Tem que ser 20% do total das minhas respostas aceitas(sem self-answer) e esse 20% do total deve ser maior que 5?

Comment: Tirando um possível erro de digitação no seu comentário. Sim, é bem isso mesmo.

Comment: qual erro que é?

Comment: @Math conta o Score tendo +1/-1 = 0? ou sem voto tbm?

Comment: "Tem que ser 20% do total das **respostas** minhas respostas aceitas(sem self-answer)". Se tirar a parte em itálico, é isso aí.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert pode ter negativos e positivos, mas a pontuação tem que ser igual a zero.